# How to split comma-separated string but exclude some words containing comma in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

Assume that we have below string:

`"test01,test02,test03,exceptional,case,test04"`

What I want is to split the string into string array, like below:

`["test01","test02","test03","exceptional,case","test04"]`

How can I do that in Java?

Comment: there are some other words as well right?? not just that

Comment: just one word `exceptional,case`

Comment: How do you know that `exceptional,case` should not be split? What is special about them? Are they embedded in quotes? Is it because they have no digits?

Comment: This is an unsolvable problem without a dictionary. How do you know the fourth coma is actually not a separator?

Comment: @how to achieve that with dictionary? All I know about this string is a word `exceptional,case`. They must be together.

Comment: exceptional,case will be treated as two words when you split using comma as a separator.

Comment: you can't, unless you hardcode each combination that should remain 'paired'. either you split on ',', or you don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This negative lookaround regex should work for you:

```
(?<!exceptional),|,(?!case)
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sV7iB3)

**Java Code:**

```
String[] arr = str.split("(?<!exceptional),|,(?!case)");
```

**Explanation:**

This regex matches a comma **if any one of these 2 conditions meet**:

1. comma is not preceded by word `exceptional` using negative lookbehind `(?<!exceptional)`
2. comma is not followed by word `case` using negative lookahead `(?!case)`

That effectively disallows splitting on comma when it is surrounded by `exceptional` and `case` on either side.

Comment: In java, should it be `str.split("(?<!exceptional),(?!case)")`

Comment: It would be great if you explain in your answer~

Comment: Thanks @zx81, I added some explanation also for OP.

Comment: Terrific. And I edited my answer to acknowledge that your answer is superior in this particular case. :)

Answer (score 1):

[@anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24300342/1078583) is great—use it. For completion, here's a general solution that is applicable to many solutions and uses a beautifully simple regex:

```
exceptional,case|(,)
```

The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `exceptional,case`. We will ignore these matches. The right side matches and captures commas to Group 1, and we know they are the right ones because they were not matched by the expression on the left. We then replace these commas by something distinctive, and split on that string.

This program shows how to use the regex (see the results at the bottom of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/AzkDoH)):

```
 String subject = "somethingelse,case,test02,test03,exceptional,case,test04,exceptional,notcase";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("exceptional,case|(,)");
Matcher m = regex.matcher(subject);
StringBuffer b= new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
if(m.group(1) != null) m.appendReplacement(b, "@@SplitHere@@");
else m.appendReplacement(b, m.group(0));
}
m.appendTail(b);
String replaced = b.toString();
String[] splits = replaced.split("@@SplitHere@@");
for (String split : splits) System.out.println(split);
```

**Reference**

- [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)
- [Article about matching a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Answer (score 0):

How can Java understand the `exceptional,case` is a single word and not to split ?

Still If there would have been some other recurring character like `""` you could have split it.

For ex. if It was

```
"test01","test02","test03","exceptional,case","test04"
```

You could split it using `","`

So in your case it is not possible, unless you use regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dead-simple answer, don't know why I didn't think of it yesterday:

```
(?<!exceptional(?=,case)),
```

**Explanation**

A comma (the last character of the regex) that is not preceded by `exceptional` followed by `,case`

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1 = "test01.test02.test03.{i}.case.test04.test03.{i}.test03.{i}.test03.{i}";
String[] arr1 =    s1.split("(?<!)\\.|\\.(?!\\{i})");

    Output:
    test01
    test02
    test03.{i}
    case
    test04
    test03.{i}
    test03.{i}
    test03.{i}
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use **split()**

Like this:

```
String[] array = "test01,test02,test03,exceptional,case,test04".split(",");
```

Comment: Please look at the question again

Comment: He wants to skip words that contain comma.